# MSSQL: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0) after loading 1000 + lines

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having some problems when returning a large number of rows from SQL Server using PHP + Datatables. My code is using one main loop then some "subloops".

Sometimes, when the number of lines gets up to 1000+ the execution is aborted and the error MSSQL: SQLSTATE[] (null) (severity 0) is shown.

Connection function:

```
function pdo_mssql($sql){

    $host = ***;
    $user = ***;
    $pass = ***;
    $db   = ***;

    try {
        $PDO = new PDO( 'dblib:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db, $user, $pass );;
    }
    catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo 'MSSQL error: ' . $e->getMessage(); exit;
    }

    $result = $PDO->query( $sql );

    if (is_array($result)){
        $row = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }else{
        $row = $result;
    }

    return $row;

}
```

Example of the script where the error occurs:

```
$sql = "SELECT ....";
$return = pdo_mssql($sql);

foreach ($return as $row){

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return2 = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Do something
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return2 = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Do something
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT ...."
    $return2 = pdomssql($sql2);

    foreach ($return2 as $row2){
        // Do something
    }

    // Show results

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code, $return2 is not being assigned in inner loop. May be you want to do

$sql2 = "SELECT ...."
$return2 = pdomssql($sql2);